# Apache2 Perl vHosts Error

Tags: mysql, apache, vhosts

I just worked through this [tutorial](http://www.dd-sign.de/tutorial-datenbank-gestuetze-vhosts-mit-variablen-mit-hilfe-von-mod_perl/) and modified the table by adding another column. I want to check the value before adding the template script. It didn't work and the script includes the template-ssl every time. It is important that this script works with MySQL, mass vhosts is not possible.

```
$My::dir = @row[3]; 
$My::encrypted = @row[4];
if ($My::encrypted == 'ssl') {
    $s->add_config(["Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/template-ssl"]);
}
else {
    $s->add_config(["Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/template-def"]);
}
```

I think the variables doesn't work but `if(@row[4] == "ssl")` also fire as true every time. Even when the DataRow contains "def".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was too simple. The error was that you compare stings with `"xx" eq "yy"` and numbers with `1 == 2`.